# Transform images to white on black and predict

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pytorch

I want to predict new customized images with LeNet model trained from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/vincentman0403/pytorch-v0-3-1b-on-mnist-by-lenet).
The customized images are black on white, so I need to convert them to white on black.
[image]

```
# Load & transform image
ori_img = Image.open('./test/2.png').convert('L')
img = np.invert(ori_img) #Transform images to white on black
t = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((32, 32)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
])
img = torch.autograd.Variable(t(img).unsqueeze(0))
ori_img.close()

# Predict
model.eval()
output = model(img)
pred = output.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1][0][0]
print('Prediction: {}'.format(pred))
```

The result I got:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-182-abbffa2ce0d8> in <module>
      7     transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
      8 ])
----> 9 img = torch.autograd.Variable(t(img).unsqueeze(0))
     10 ori_img.close()

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py in __call__(self, img)
     59     def __call__(self, img):
     60         for t in self.transforms:
---> 61             img = t(img)
     62         return img
     63 

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py in __call__(self, img)
    196             PIL Image: Rescaled image.
    197         """
--> 198         return F.resize(img, self.size, self.interpolation)
    199 
    200     def __repr__(self):

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py in resize(img, size, interpolation)
    236     """
    237     if not _is_pil_image(img):
--> 238         raise TypeError('img should be PIL Image. Got {}'.format(type(img)))
    239     if not (isinstance(size, int) or (isinstance(size, Iterable) and len(size) == 2)):
    240         raise TypeError('Got inappropriate size arg: {}'.format(size))

TypeError: img should be PIL Image. Got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

When I comment `img = np.invert(ori_img)` I get no errors, but all prediction results are `2`s.

Someone could help? Thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this function: [PIL.Image.fromarray](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray) to create a PIL Image from your numpy array, and then you can use the [PIL.ImageOps.invert](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.invert) function to invert colors. Then your `img` variable should be the right type and inverted.

Comment: I add these code: `a = np.asarray(ori_img) im = Image.fromarray(a) img = ImageOps.invert(im)`, do you think it's correct?

Comment: @ahbon I'm sorry, I never saw this comment. Did this solution end up working?

Comment: Yes, I think so